# Fetch very first date index of a given date in double array

Tags: c#, datetime

I am having a `double` array of dates(converted to double) using `DateTime.ToOaDate()`. It also consist of  `Datetime` In `Double` like  -

```
26-July-2018 14:00:00
27-July-2018 12:09:00
27-July-2018 12:10:00
27-July-2018 12:15:00
28-July-2018 12:50:00
28-July-2018 13:40:00
```

Now, I have a specific date in double of say `27-July-2018 12:15:00`. I want the index from where the first date time of `27-July-2018` started. In the above case, I want the index of `27-July-2018 12:09:00`.

Please note that I have explained things in DateTime format. But in
reality all of this data is in `double` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try is:

```
DateTime tocheck = new DateTime();
tocheck = DateTime.Parse("27-July-2018 12:15:00");
double tochkd = tocheck.ToOADate();

int index = dateDouble.IndexOf(dateDouble.FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == (int)tochkd));
```

or you can also do is

```
int index = dateDouble.IndexOf(dateDouble.FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == tocheck.Date.ToOADate());
```

output:-

```
   result = 1
```

if the value is present it will return index else it will return -1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<DateTime> dt = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2018,7,26,14,0,0),// 26-July-2018 14:00:00
    new DateTime(2018,7,27,12,9,0),//27 - July - 2018 12:09:00
    new DateTime(2018,7,27,12,10,0),//27 - July - 2018 12:10:00
    new DateTime(2018,7,27,12,15,0),//27 - July - 2018 12:15:00
    new DateTime(2018,7,28,12,50,0),//28 - July - 2018 12:50:00
    new DateTime(2018,7,28,13,40,0)//28 - July - 2018 13:40:00
};

List<double> dbl = dt.Select(d => d.ToOADate()).ToList();
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2018, 7, 27, 12, 15, 0);
double startDateDbl = (new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, 0, 0, 0)).ToOADate();
List<double> filteredDates = dbl.Where(d => d >= startDateDbl).ToList();
```